# No .local/bin folder

Tags: 14.04

The top answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313876/after-installing-with-pip-jupyter-command-not-found) stackoverflow question says the executable to run Jupyter is in the ~/.local/bin folder.

I have no .local/bin folder.  Is this normal?  Where would I find the executable then?

Since I use Python 2.7, I "pip install jupyter" to install Jupyter.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/997813/edit) your question and add information on how you installed Jupyter. Did you install it as `root` or using the `sudo` prefix?

Comment: According to http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/jupyter-directories.html the jupyter folder should be in `~/.local/share`.

Comment: What happens if you run the command `which jupyter`? Edit your question with the answer please.